# How to upload to a specific folder a set of files to AWS S3 based on file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a set of subject files for a research project and corresponding subject folders on AWS. The files are organized on my desktop as:

100001/100001_FILE.gz 
100002/100001_FILE.gz 
etc

Such that 100001, 100002 correspond to a specific subject. I want to upload these to an S3 bucket that contains 'folders' that are the subjectIDs

bucketname/100001 
bucketname/100002 
etc

What I want to do is upload 100001_FILE.gz from my computer and place it in bucketname/100001 on S3. I don't have a lot of experience with S3 and so any thoughts on how best do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this from your computer, just head to https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-east-1# (US N. Virginia) region and locate the S3 bucket, the folder and click on the "Upload" button.

**If you like to upload it directly from your computer without a browser**, please download the AWS CLI https://aws.amazon.com/es/cli/ (Search for your computer operating system).

Create an IAM user and download the Access key and Secret Key and [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) your terminal. Then you can upload an object in your computer like this:

```
aws s3 cp <path_to_your_object_in_pc> s3://bucketname/100001
```

and

```
aws s3 cp <path_to_your_object_in_pc> s3://bucketname/100002
```

Comment: Thanks! What I am hoping to do is automate this since I have over 1000 files and folders to upload. Would I be able to run this on my computer and have it automate this process using the aws CLI codes you indicated?

Comment: Sure!! just create a bash script "example.sh" to upload the files with the commands I showed you in example *and* create a cronjob (if you are on Linux) or Scheduler task (if you are on Windows). It's totally doable.